# PostgreSQL installation fails with macOS Monterey 12.4

Tags: postgresql, macos

I'm using MacOS Monterey 12.4 Intel chip, and trying Postgresql installation from
https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads I think every version for Maos.

every installation attempt turned out the same, the program crashed as soon as it wanted to choose a password, while entering any character.

can anyone help me to install?

Comment: Never had any issues with Postgres.app: https://postgresapp.com

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue on a 2020 M1 Macbook on MacOS Monterey 12.2.1 when I try to install 14.3. I get all the way to the Provide password for database superuser. Then once entering a password the program crashes. I'll probably end up using the postgresapp version until this is fixed. The latest version of the app (14.3) is universal so it should work with the m1s (if anyone else has this problem with m1). That is the best solution I've got so far.

Edit: You may want to try installing with Homebrew as well. https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/postgresql#default. I'm going to try this later.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).